# How to use pgdump to download specific rows?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I want the exact inserts for only a subset of rows in a table. For argument's sake, let's say that set is determined by:

```
select * from uses where created > current_date - 2
```

How would I use pg_dump to get the exact inserts for those specific rows?

**UPDATE**

This is what I have so far:

```
pg_dump -host 111.222.333.444 --port 5432 --username "postgress" --password "XXXXXXXXXX" --inserts -f bla.sql
```

Missing link is the part where I can alter this dump with a sql query.

Comment: Copy the rows to a temp table and `pg_dump` the temp table.

Comment: Although a decent solution, can't do that in Prod.

Comment: You can use `psql` command `/copy` to get desired rows into csv file from Prod. Then `/copy` them to test postgres instance and reexport.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko: it's `\copy` not `/copy`